# iOS inapp purchases receipt additional payload

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

In my application users can make purchases linked to their accounts in the system, not apple ID. As usual iOS app sends App Store receipt to server, which validates it. I want to know, that each transaction inside receipt belongs to specific user account. One way to do this, is sending additional parameters further to receipt like:

```
receipt: String, login: String, platform: String
```

Receipt digital signature validation make sure that the data inside is valid and not replaced by hacker. If parameters (login and platform) will be inside receipt, validation will be completely safe, and valid digital signature tells that all purchases are valid and belongs to account. Otherwise, one receipt can be sent with different logins and allows multiple users to have purchases without paying. To prevent this, for instance, all bundle (receipt, login, platform) can be additionally signed and added check for unique pairs transactionID, userId.
My question is there any way to put additional transaction parameters to receipt, or another common way to archive linkage between purchases in receipt and user account?